Movie where older man serially seduces naive girls and then abandons them
This movie is possibly from the 1990s and I think I saw it on IFC.  
There is a female lead who is a thin blonde. The male lead is much older and I think looked a lot like Gabriel Byrne. He was some sort of artist or author.
In one scene, he seduces her while she is lying face down on a sofa reading a book out loud.  
The climax of the film is when he sends her out of their motel room under some pretext, then locks the door and refuses to let her back in while she cries.  At the end there is a table of women that have all gone through the same experience with the same man.

"a table of women"?

Found it!  The movie was Guinevere (1999) starting Sarah Polley and Stephen Rea.  He was actually a photographer and all of the women gather together at the end because he is dying. 
